# CheckBoxList items check un check in code behind

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables:

1. has_service
2. Service.

I want to get the items inside table 1 and compare then to the second table and see if there is a match. The item should be shown as selected.

Are there any problems with my code?

```
ListItem thItm;

//List all services in system DB.
var AllSrvs = from s in db.services                      
              select s;

//Get current request-services ID's
var reqSrvs = (from rs in db.has_services
               where rs.request_id == Convert.ToInt32(Request["reqID"].Trim())
               select rs.service_id).ToArray();

foreach (service se in AllSrvs)
{
    thItm = new ListItem();
    thItm.Text = se.service_name_en;
    thItm.Value = se.service_id.ToString();



    for (int i = 0; i < reqSrvs.Count();i++ )
    {

        if (reqSrvs[i] ==Convert.ToInt32( se.service_id))
        {
            thItm.Selected = true;

        }
        else
        {
            thItm.Selected = false;
        }               
    }

    RequestServicesCheckBoxList.Items.Add(thItm);
}
```

Comment: Does the code work? If not, do you get an exception, or what happens instead of what you want? If the code does work, this is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Samuel .
The code as I see it work fine except the check boxes aren't  checked as needed :(

Comment: What stage of the page life cycle are you executing this?

Comment: Why do you have Response.Write( "<hr>");  ?????

Answer (score 1):

**Thank You all. :)**
I have figured it :)
The problem ws with the "else" part.
 Removed it and it's working fine now...

```
 ListItem thItm;

//List all services in system DB.
var AllSrvs = from s in db.services                      
          select s;

//Get current request-services ID's
var reqSrvs = (from rs in db.has_services
           where rs.request_id == Convert.ToInt32(Request["reqID"].Trim())
           select rs.service_id).ToArray();

 foreach (service se in AllSrvs)
  {
thItm = new ListItem();
thItm.Text = se.service_name_en;
thItm.Value = se.service_id.ToString();



for (int i = 0; i < reqSrvs.Count();i++ )
{

    if (reqSrvs[i] ==Convert.ToInt32( se.service_id))
    {
        thItm.Selected = true;

    }
   // else
   // {
   //     thItm.Selected = false;
   // }               
}

RequestServicesCheckBoxList.Items.Add(thItm);
```

}